# add value to a list and convert to list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm reading through some log files and have a list of urls like this:

url looks like this with new line after every url

```
http://domain1.com
http://domain2.com
http://domain3.com
http://domain4.com
```

I now want to make a tuple and add a single value to each url. All values are the same.
It should look like this.

```
('http://domain1.com', 3)
('http://domain2.com', 3)
('http://domain3.com', 3)
('http://domain4.com', 3)
```

And finally, for further processing I need a list of tuples that should look like this:

```
[('http://domain1.com', 3), ('http://domain2.com', 3), ('http://domain3.com',3)...]
```

This is what i tried by myself:

```
#split urls with comma
separated_urls = url.split(', ')
num__of_lines = sum(1 for line in separated_urls)

#make a list of 3s for the length of the url list
list_of_threes = [3] * num__of_lines

combined_list = zip(separated_urls, list_of_threes)
final_list = tuple(combined_list)
print final_list
```

this gives me following output:

```
(('http://domain1.com', 3),)
(('http://domain2.com', 3),)
(('http://domain3.com', 3),)
(('http://domain4.com', 3),)
```

Can someone provide me a little help, to get the desired output?

Thanks

Comment: `combined_list` is fine since `zip()` generates a list of tuples.

Comment: Isn't `num__of_lines = sum(1 for line in separated_urls)` a very long way of writing `num_of_lines = len(separated_urls)`?

Comment: @Trengot well, you are right

Comment: why did you add the line 'final_list = tuple(combined_list)'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension

```
#split urls with comma
separated_urls = url.split('\n')
final_list = [(url,3) for url in separated_urls]
```

EDIT: use `split('\n')` or (`split()` as newline is default) to split the url list up rather than `split(', ')`

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me [('http://domain1.com', 3)]\n[('http://domain2.com', 3)]\n  and so on. I do need it like this: [('http://domain1.com', 3), ('http://domain2.com', 3), ('http://domain3.com',3)...]

Comment: Could you add what `url` is to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways easily.

1) Old school for loop way:

```
output_list = []
for url in url.split():
    output_list.append((url, 3))
```

2) Or the list comprehension way, as @Trengot mentioned:

```
output_list = [(url, 3) for url in url.split()]
```

The old school way is better suited if you wish to do any changes to the list and check some more before creating the output_list. For simple cases(even with a condition check), list comprehensions are the way to go :-)

EDIT: Reading through your comments, I guess you need to split them through "\n" character rather than comma separated. Updated the code accordingly, as split by default split the characters with "\n".

Answer (score 0):

in code statement `final_list = tuple(combined_list)` is converting `list` into `tuple`.

So if you want output as `list` and items of list as `tuple` then you can remove above statement.

check by `print combined_list` statement in your code.

---

Use [List Comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
>>> urls = """
... http://domain1.com
... http://domain2.com
... http://domain3.com
... http://domain4.com"""

>>> print [(i, 3) for i in urls.split('\n') if i.strip()]
[('http://domain1.com', 3), ('http://domain2.com', 3), ('http://domain3.com', 3), ('http://domain4.com', 3)]
```

Comment: well, then i get : [('http://domain1.com', 3)]. I do need a list containing all items like this: [('http://domain1.com', 3), ('http://domain2.com', 3), ('http://domain3.com',3)...]

Comment: on python 2.7.3: I get value of `combined_list` as ` [('http://domain1.com', 3), ('http://domain2.com', 3), ('http://domain3.com', 3), ('http://domain4.com', 3)]` by your code.

Comment: I also updated, check if it is useful or not. Handle empty new line condition.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you have found the answer.
Your code is accurate till the following lines

```
url = "http://domain1.com, http://domain2.com, http://domain3.com, http://domain4.com"
separated_urls = url.split(', ')
list_of_threes = [3] * len(separated_urls)
combined_list = zip(separated_urls, list_of_threes)
```

The problem is your casting. Just cast the `combined_list` to a `list`

```
print (list(combined_list))
```

and bingo, you get your output

```
[('http://domain1.com', 3), ('http://domain2.com', 3), ('http://domain3.com', 3), ('http://domain4.com', 3)]
```